# How to put a node in a dictionary using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is the XML file which I have:

```
<Root>
    <Level1>
        <Foo ID="1" Count="20" />
        <Foo ID="2" Count="28" />
        <Foo ID="3" Count="25" />
    </Level1>
</Root>
```

I only have one Level 1 element in my XML, and inside of it there several Foo nodes.

How can I get that Foo nodes in a dictionary?
I mean `Dictionary<int, int>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var dictionary =
    doc.Root
        .Element("Level1")
        .Elements("Foo")
        .ToDictionary(
            e => (int)e.Attribute("Id"),
            e => (int)e.Attribute("Count"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`XElement.Parse("XML here").Descendants("Foo").Select( s => s).ToDictionary( x=> x.Attribute("ID").Value, x=> x.Attribute("Count").Value))`